# How to fit a mixture of 2D Gaussian in BUGS/JAGS?

Tags: bayesian, multivariate-normal-distribution, graphical-model, jags, bugs

I am trying to estimate the parameters of a mixture of 2D Gaussian distribution using JAGS. I first created two components from a multivariate normal distribution and then combined them to get a mixture model. Here is the code:

```
sigxy <- matrix(c(1, 0.9, 0.9, 1), nrow=2, ncol=2)
comp1 <- rmvnorm(n=1000, mean=c(0,0), sigma=sigxy)
comp2 <- rmvnorm(n=4000, mean=c(10, 10), sigma=sigxy)
xy <- rbind(comp1, comp2)
```

My latent variables are mean of each distribution in every dimension. I already know how to write the model in BUGS syntax to estimate the parameters of mixture of 1D Gaussian distributions (BUGS [tutorial](http://www.di.fc.ul.pt/%7Ejpn/r/bugs/part2.html#mixture-of-gaussians)). Unfortunately, I couldn't find any solution for mixture of 2D. Based on this [discussion](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/multivariate-gaussian-mixture-model-help/14208/18), people are saying that this is an open research question. I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas on how to write the model?

A more general question, Do you recommend any tool other that BUGS to estimate the parameters of a graphical model with latent and observed variables using Gibbs sampling? I know that there are couple of R [packages](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/gR.html) but none of them can handle multiple latent variables, and the methods don't sound promising for my problem.

Thank you for your help.

Shiva.